# Merge two array together in a session with PHP

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, session, multidimensional-array

**Problem:**

I have two array where one produce a category and the second produce items for the category. I would like the items to be inside each category but I can't make it work.

**PHP code:**

```
foreach ($current['Children'] as $key => $value)
{
    $query = "SELECT * FROM betyg_items WHERE CID = '{$key}' AND Status = '1' ORDER BY CID ASC";
    $result = mysql_query($query) or die ('Database Error (' . mysql_errno() . ') ' . mysql_error());

    $_SESSION['keys'][$key] = $value;

    while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
    {
        $_SESSION['items'][$row['IID']] = array(
                                        'ID' => $row['IID'],
                                        'CID' => $row['CID'],
                                        'Description' => $row['Description']
                                    );
    }
}
```

**$_SESSION['keys'] will contain:**

```
Array
(
    [2] => Integration av källorna
    [3] => Belysning av egna resultat
    [4] => Referenser
)
```

**$_SESSION['items'] will contain:**

```
Array
(
    [1] => Array
        (
            [ID] => 1
            [CID] => 2
            [Description] => Källorna refereras separat
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [ID] => 2
            [CID] => 2
            [Description] => Vissa försök till sammanbindning
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [ID] => 6
            [CID] => 3
            [Description] => Inga jämförelser mellan egna och andras resultat
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [ID] => 7
            [CID] => 3
            [Description] => Kort redovisning av likheter och skillnader mellan egna och andras resultat
        )

    [5] => Array
        (
            [ID] => 11
            [CID] => 4
            [Description] => Många formella felaktigheter i referens- och litteraturförteckning; ej primärkällor
        )

    [6] => Array
        (
            [ID] => 12
            [CID] => 4
            [Description] => Vissa formella fel, vissa källor av mindre kvalitet
        )
)
```

**Question:**

How do I get each item into the array index it correspond by using the CID value?

**Scenario:**

For instance, all CID's that contain the number 2 should go into "[2] => Integration av källorna", and so forth.

**Desired output:**

```
Array
(
    [2] => Integration av källorna

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [ID] => 1
                    [CID] => 2
                    [Description] => Källorna refereras separat
                )

            [2] => Array
                (
                    [ID] => 2
                    [CID] => 2
                    [Description] => Vissa försök till sammanbindning
                )

    [3] => Belysning av egna resultat

            [3] => Array
                (
                    [ID] => 6
                    [CID] => 3
                    [Description] => Inga jämförelser mellan egna och andras resultat
                )

            [4] => Array
                (
                    [ID] => 7
                    [CID] => 3
                    [Description] => Kort redovisning av likheter och skillnader mellan egna och andras resultat
                )

    [4] => Referenser

            [5] => Array
                (
                    [ID] => 11
                    [CID] => 4
                    [Description] => Många formella felaktigheter i referens- och litteraturförteckning; ej primärkällor
                )

            [6] => Array
                (
                    [ID] => 12
                    [CID] => 4
                    [Description] => Vissa formella fel, vissa källor av mindre kvalitet
                )
)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$final_arr = array();
$i = 0;

foreach ($current['Children'] as $key => $value)
{
    $query = "SELECT * FROM betyg_items WHERE CID = '{$key}' AND Status = '1' ORDER BY CID ASC";
    $result = mysql_query($query) or die ('Database Error (' . mysql_errno() . ') ' . mysql_error());

    $final_arr[$i]['key'] = $value;

    while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
    {
         $final_arr[$i]['items'][] = array(
                            'ID' => $row['IID'],
                            'CID' => $row['CID'],
                            'Description' => $row['Description']
                          );
    }
   $i++;
}
```

FINAL OUTPUT WILL BE:
**$final_arr**

```
Array
(
    [0] => 
            ['key']=> Integration av källorna
            ['items'] => 
                 [0] => Array
                 (
                    [ID] => 1
                    [CID] => 2
                    [Description] => Källorna refereras separat
                 )

                 [1] => Array
                 (
                    [ID] => 2
                    [CID] => 2
                    [Description] => Vissa försök till sammanbindning
                  )
```

Comment: How would I have to do if I want the items to be [0] => Källorna refereras separat AND [1] => Vissa försök till sammanbindning ?

Comment: You can access to them via: $final_arr[0]['items'][0]['description'] AND $final_arr[0]['items'][1]['description'].